# Feature importance determination and correlation

Tags: python, heatmap, correlation, feature-selection

I want to know which of my varibles have the strongest effect on `SalePrice`
in my DataFrame `df_train`.

```
   Id  MSSubClass MSZoning    ...     SaleType  SaleCondition SalePrice
0   1          60       RL    ...           WD         Normal    208500
1   2          20       RL    ...           WD         Normal    181500
2   3          60       RL    ...           WD         Normal    223500
3   4          70       RL    ...           WD        Abnorml    140000
4   5          60       RL    ...           WD         Normal    250000
```

For this purpose, I have analized correlation,as well as `feature_importances_` of sklearn.
The code for correlation and visualization, with heatmap, is:

```
corrmat = df_train.corr()
k = 20 #number of variables for heatmap
cols = corrmat.nlargest(k, 'SalePrice')['SalePrice'].index
cm = np.corrcoef(df_train[cols].values.T)
sns.set(font_scale=1.25)
hm = sns.heatmap(cm, cbar=True, annot=True, square=True, fmt='.2f', annot_kws={'size': 10}, yticklabels=cols.values, xticklabels=cols.values)
plt.show()
```

And for feature importance determination is:

```
feature_labels = np.array(['OverallQual', 'GrLivArea', 'SimplOverallQual', 'ExterQual', 'GarageCars', 'KitchenQual', 'SimplExterQual', 'GarageArea', 'SimplKitchenQual', 'TotalBsmtSF', 'FullBath', 'YearBuilt', '1stFlrSF', 'YearRemodAdd', 'TotRmsAbvGrd', 'Fireplaces', 'HeatingQC', 'LotArea', 'MasVnrArea']) importance = model.feature_importances_ feature_indexes_by_importance = importance.argsort()

indices = np.argsort(importance)[::-1] for index in feature_indexes_by_importance:
    print('{}-{:.2f}%'.format(feature_labels[index], (importance[index] *100.0)))
```

`'OverallQual', 'GrLivArea'` and `'SimplQual'`are the most correlated variables with `SalePrice` according to heatmap.
And according to `feature importance` most important ones are:

```
GarageArea-9.71% 

GrLivArea-15.43%

LotArea-17.46%
```

What is the problem that could explain why correlation and `feature_importances_` of sklearn don´t correlate?
Thanks

Comment: How are these features correlated among themselves?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you are talking about forest of trees `feature_importances_`? (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_forest_importances.html)

Correlation measures a linear correlation between the features and your output, random forest use non linear classification that have nothing to do with linear correlation, and will be able to extract the features that non linearly have the most importance in the task.